# What is elastic search bounded by? Is it cpu, memory etc

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running elastic search in my personal box.

- Memory: 6GB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3120M CPU @ 2.50GHz × 4
- OS: Ubuntu 12.04 -  64-bit

ElasticSearch Settings: Only running locally

- Version : 1.2.2
- ES_MIN_MEM=3g
- ES_MAX_MEM=3g
- threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 3000
- indices.fielddata.cache.size: 25%
- http.compression: true
- bootstrap.mlockall: true
- script.disable_dynamic: true
- cluster.name: elasticsearch
- **index size: 252MB**

Scenario:
I am trying to test the performance of my bulk queries/aggregations. The test case is to run asynchronous http requests to node.js which in turn will call elastic search. The tests are running from a Java method. Started with 50 requests at a time. Each request is divided and parallized in to two asynchronous(async.parallel) bulk queries in node.js. I am using [node-elasticsearch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/elasticsearch) api (uses elasticsearch 1.3 api). The two bulk queries contain 13 and 10 queries respectively.And the two are asynchronously sent to elastic search from node.js. When the Elastic Search returns, the query results are combined and sent back to the test case.

Observations:
I see that all the cpu cores are utilized 100%. Memory is utilized around 90%. The response time for all 50 requests combined is 30 seconds. If I run just the single queries each alone, in the bulk queries, each are returning in less than 100 milli-seconds. Node.js is taking negligible time to forward requests to elastic search and combine responses from elastic search.
Even if run the test case synchronously from java, the response time does not change. I may say that elastic search is not doing parallel processing. Is this because I am CPU or memory bound? ***One more observation: if I change heap size for elastic search from 1 - 3GB, the response time does not change.***

**Also I am pasting top command output:**

```
    top - 18:04:12 up  4:29,  5 users,  load average: 5.93, 5.16, 4.15
Tasks: 224 total,   3 running, 221 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 98.2%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.8%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   5955796k total,  5801920k used,   153876k free,     1548k buffers
Swap:  6133756k total,   708336k used,  5425420k free,   460436k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                           
17410 root      20   0 7495m 3.3g  27m S  366 58.6   5:09.57 java                                                                              
15356 rmadd     20   0 1015m 125m 3636 S   19  2.2   1:14.03 node
```

Questions:
Is this expected, because I am running Elastic Search in my local machine and not in a cluster? Can I improve my performance in my local machine? I would definitely start a cluster. But I want to know, how to improve the performance scalably. What is it that the elastic search is bound to?

I am not able to find this in forums. And am sure this would help others. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I suggest that you use a load test like Tsung or JMeter to benchmark your local cluster correctly. There is lots of reasons that can alter elasticsearch performances, basically in your case I think it can be disk i/o, and the RAM maybe and you should also be careful if elasticsearch is swapping or not. You didn't give us any information about your data size. The bulk size may be to much you'll also need to monitor that. (A detailed answer would be very long to fit actually here)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added more details. I set the setting, "bootstrap.mlockall: true", which should not allow swapping. Can you give me any direction?

Comment: About the swapping issue. what you did is not enough for disabling swap. You'll also need to do these commands 'swapoff -a && swapon -a' followed by 'sysctl vm.swappiness=1'. You'll need to check if that worked with 'cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness' it should be equal to one.

Comment: Secondly, your index is very small what kind of query are you running on to loose performance? I'm running very complex script queries on a 20GB index and it answer me with fractions of a second. What do you mean by bulk queries/aggregations?

Comment: ElasticSearch Mapping: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0de244ae57db2c08e5fe                    ElasticSeach Sample Record: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23214658ba2eec96540f                                ElasticSearch First Bulk Query: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/391b510dfc9467158a8b                        ElasticSearch Second Bulk Query: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e1bcba83fcf564a8ff39                         The two bulk queries are run in parallel.

Comment: The two bulk queries are run in parallel. I am sending 50 concurrent requests from a Java test case to NodeJs. In NodeJs, each request is divided in to the above two bulk requests and ran in parallel. The response from these two are combined and sent back to the test case. The time taken for all 50 is 30 secs. And single request is taking 1.4 seconds.

Comment: There is 30 aggregations in the first bulk request!! Why would anyone do that? I don't even know where to begin... :(

Comment: I can do away with combining these aggregations into one single bulk query. Do you think, it would be faster, if I call these 30 aggregations not as a single bulk request, but by 30 parallel search requests? What is your suggestion? Really appreciated for your help.

Comment: It would much better if you running those requests in parallel of course!! That's lots of aggs to do in one time! so if elasticsearch answers you in 1.4 sec, that's an awesome time!

Comment: I see similar response times even if I run the queries in parallel, instead of grouping them as a bulk query.

Comment: how are you measuring that?

Comment: I am measuring from NodeJs as well as the java test case. Whenever the response comes from elastic search to NodeJs, I log the time. And as well the response when it comes to Java test case from NodeJs. Can you answer the question? These comments are getting huge.

Comment: I know but I still can't answer the question since I can't reproduce the benchmarks...

Comment: What else we should see, when measuring these benchmarks? And please give me some debugging/tuning steps.